connections between two graphs
I would like to be able to represent this type of image:

Separately, I can more or less (it could probably be improved) represent each of the two parts but I am faced with two difficulties:

the horizontal axis is not aligned on each of the figures which therefore shifts the vertical values
I cannot make the connections between the two graphs

My code :
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\mathcode`\.="013B%virgule décimale en mode math
%\usepackage{tikz}% chargé automatiquement par pgfplots
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={~},use comma}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}            % Permet l'affichage de deux axes y


\begin{document}
    
    \def\TebA{78.4}%ethanol
    \def\TebB{64.7}%methanol
    
    
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[% mise en forme du graphique :
            xmin=-0.2,xmax=1.2,
            ymin=57,ymax=95,    % <<<
            samples = 100,
            no markers,
            ticks=none,
            hide x axis,
            hide y axis,
            ]
            
            
            % tracé concentration AH3 :
            
            \addplot[mark=none, draw=blue] expression[domain=0:1]{\TebA-5*x-7*x*x-2*x*x*x};
            %\addlegendentry{courbe de rosée};
            
            \addplot[mark=none, draw=red] expression[domain=0:1]{\TebA-32*x+21*x*x-3*x*x*x};
            %\addlegendentry{courbe d'ébullition};
            
            
            %\draw[dotted,line width=.5pt] (axis cs: \Veq,-1) -- +(axis cs: 0,3);
            \draw (-0.1,78.4) node{$T_{eb,A}$};
            \draw (1.1,64.7) node[below]{$T_{eb,B}$};
            
            % ~~~ extra axis', utilizing clipping to min/max area ~~~~~~
            \draw[->] (axis cs: 0,60) -- (axis cs: 0,90)node[above]{A pur};
            \draw[->] (axis cs: 1,60) -- (axis cs: 1,90)node[above]{B pur};
            \draw[->] (axis cs: 0,60) -- (axis cs: 1.1,60);
            \draw[->] (axis cs: 0,60) -- (axis cs: 1.1,60) node[anchor=north west]{$x_B$};
            
            \node at(axis cs:0.3,80) {Vapeur};
            \node at(axis cs:0.5,71) {L+V};
            \node at(axis cs:0.3,65) {Liquide};
            
            \draw[dashed, orange] (axis cs:0.6,60)node[below]{$x$} -- (0.6,72.45) -- (0.6,80);
            \draw[dashed, Magenta] (axis cs:0.6,66.11)-- (axis cs:0.93,66.11) -- (axis cs:0.93,60)node[below]{$x'_G$};
            \draw[dashed, Maroon] (axis cs:0.6,72.45)-- (axis cs:0.22,72.45) -- (axis cs:0.22,60)node[below]{$x''_L$};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \quad%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[% mise en forme du graphique :
            xmin=-0.2,xmax=1.2,
            ymin=57,ymax=95,    % <<<
            samples = 100,
            no markers,
            ticks=none,
            hide x axis,
            hide y axis,
            legend style={xshift=-1.8cm, 
                yshift=-5cm,
                anchor = south east,
                font=\tiny},
            ]
            
            
            % tracé concentration AH3 :
            
        \addplot coordinates {(0.1,60) (0.25,66.11) (0.75,72.45) (0.9,80)}  ;

            
            
            %\draw[dotted,line width=.5pt] (axis cs: \Veq,-1) -- +(axis cs: 0,3);
            \draw (-0.1,66.1) node[above]{$T'$};
            \draw (-0.1,72.45) node[above]{$T''$};
            
            % ~~~ extra axis', utilizing clipping to min/max area ~~~~~~
            \draw[->] (axis cs: 0,60) -- (axis cs: 0,90)node[above]{A pur};
            \draw[->] (axis cs: 1,60) -- (axis cs: 1,90)node[above]{B pur};
            \draw[->] (axis cs: 0,60) -- (axis cs: 1.1,60);
            \draw[->] (axis cs: 0,60) -- (axis cs: 1.1,60) node[anchor=north west]{$temps$};
            
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


If someone could help me.

For the first question

the horizontal axis is not aligned on each of the figures which
therefore shifts the vertical values

In the pgfplots's documentation section 4.19.3 Horizontal Alignment we can read

A single tikzpicture environment in which the complete alignment is
done

In section 4.19.1 we have (s.right of east)

For the second question


I cannot make the connections between the two graphs

.
EDIT: the tikzmark library is not necessary (comment from Qrrbrbirlbel)
Code
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\mathcode`\.="013B%virgule décimale en mode math
%\usepackage{tikz}% chargé automatiquement par pgfplots
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={~},use comma}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}            % Permet l'affichage de deux axes y


\begin{document}
    
    \def\TebA{78.4}%ethanol
    \def\TebB{64.7}%methanol
    
    
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[% mise en forme du graphique :
            name=main plot,%<---  added
            xmin=-0.2,xmax=1.2,
            ymin=57,ymax=95,    % <<<
            samples = 100,
            no markers,
            ticks=none,
            hide x axis,
            hide y axis,
            ]
                
            % tracé concentration AH3 :
            
            \addplot[mark=none, draw=blue] expression[domain=0:1]{\TebA-5*x-7*x*x-2*x*x*x};
            %\addlegendentry{courbe de rosée};
            
            \addplot[mark=none, draw=red] expression[domain=0:1]{\TebA-32*x+21*x*x-3*x*x*x};
            %\addlegendentry{courbe d'ébullition};
            
            
            %\draw[dotted,line width=.5pt] (axis cs: \Veq,-1) -- +(axis cs: 0,3);
            \draw (-0.1,78.4) node{$T_{eb,A}$};
            \draw (1.1,64.7) node[below]{$T_{eb,B}$};
            
            % ~~~ extra axis', utilizing clipping to min/max area ~~~~~~
            \draw[->] (axis cs: 0,60) -- (axis cs: 0,90)node[above]{A pur};
            \draw[->] (axis cs: 1,60) -- (axis cs: 1,90)node[above]{B pur};
            \draw[->] (axis cs: 0,60) -- (axis cs: 1.1,60);
            \draw[->] (axis cs: 0,60) -- (axis cs: 1.1,60) node[anchor=north west]{$x_B$};
            
            \node at(axis cs:0.3,80) {Vapeur};
            \node at(axis cs:0.5,71) {L+V};
            \node at(axis cs:0.3,65) {Liquide};
            
            \draw[dashed, orange] (axis cs:0.6,60)node[below]{$x$} -- (0.6,72.45) -- (0.6,80);
            \draw[dashed, Magenta] (axis cs:0.6,66.11)-- (axis cs:0.93,66.11) -- (axis cs:0.93,60)node[below]{$x'_G$};
            \draw[dashed, Maroon] (axis cs:0.6,72.45)node(D1){}-- (axis cs:0.22,72.45) -- (axis cs:0.22,60)node[below]{$x''_L$};
        \end{axis}
    % \end{tikzpicture}%
    % \quad%
    % \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[% mise en forme du graphique :
            %%%%%%%% added
            at={(main plot.right of east)},
            xshift=1em,
            anchor=west,
            %%%%%%%%%%%%
            xmin=-0.2,xmax=1.2,
            ymin=57,ymax=95,    % <<<
            samples = 100,
            no markers,
            ticks=none,
            hide x axis,
            hide y axis,
            legend style={xshift=-1.8cm, 
                yshift=-5cm,
                anchor = south east,
                font=\tiny},
            ]
            
            
            % tracé concentration AH3 :
            
        \addplot coordinates {(0.1,60) (0.25,66.11) (0.75,72.45) (0.9,80)}  ;

            \coordinate(d1) at (0.75,72.45);%<--- added
            
            %\draw[dotted,line width=.5pt] (axis cs: \Veq,-1) -- +(axis cs: 0,3);
            \draw (-0.1,66.1) node[above]{$T'$};
            \draw (-0.1,72.45) node[above]{$T''$};
            
            % ~~~ extra axis', utilizing clipping to min/max area ~~~~~~
            \draw[->] (axis cs: 0,60) -- (axis cs: 0,90)node[above]{A pur};
            \draw[->] (axis cs: 1,60) -- (axis cs: 1,90)node[above]{B pur};
            \draw[->] (axis cs: 0,60) -- (axis cs: 1.1,60);
            \draw[->] (axis cs: 0,60) -- (axis cs: 1.1,60) node[anchor=north west]{$temps$};            
        \end{axis}
        \draw[red,->] (D1) -- (d1);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



The code doesn't use the tikzmark library's functionality. The remember picture functionality is built in with TikZ. That said, you don't need even that. Just put \draw[red,->] (D1) -- (d1); in the first tikzpicture.

@Qrrbirlbel Thanks, I updated the answer
